# ViewBox default width and height

Tags: wpf, user-controls, viewbox

i've created usercontrol with viewbox as a main container.
If i add this usercontrol to a window it will place all area of it.
How to set up default width and height for the control?

```
<UserControl>
    ...
    <Viewbox>
        <Grid Height="167" Width="178">
            <ed:RegularPolygon Fill="#FFF4F4F5" InnerRadius="1" PointCount="3" Stroke="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="-39,52,69,52" >
                <ed:RegularPolygon.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </ed:RegularPolygon.RenderTransform>
            </ed:RegularPolygon>            
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to set the dimensions for a particular control. Hard coding exact `Width` and `Height` properties is the least recommended. Instead of that, you could try using the `MinHeight`, `MaxHeight`, `MinWidth` and/or `MaxWidth` properties that all controls have.

Another alternative is to set some restrictions using the `ColumnDefinitions` or `WidthDefinitions` of a parent [`Grid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid(v=vs.110).aspx) if the control resides in one.